# I've installed package pythonping on 3 machines all 3 fail saying "No Module named 'pythonping'

Tags: python-3.x, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pythonping

[image]

I need to this to work in WSL I've also tried different interpreters within VSCode but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's relevant to anyone but the fix was a simple -E

Using the "sudo -E" to preserve the environment variables"

```
sudo -E python3 ping.py
```